# how to change port number for Jenkins installation In Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins

I am trying to install jenkins in ubuntu. I have followed the commands below:

```
wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | apt-key add -

echo deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list
```

then

```
apt-get update
```

and

```
apt-get install jenkins
```

but It shows

> - Starting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server Jenkins                           The selected http port (8080) seems to be in use by another program 
>     Please select another port to use for jenkins

Need help on how to set a different port for Jenkins to run.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

First open the `/etc/default/jenkins` file.
Then under `JENKINS_ARGS` section, you can change the port like this `HTTP_PORT=9999`.

Then you should restart Jenkins with `sudo service jenkins restart`.
Then to check the status use this command `sudo systemctl status jenkins`

Comment: Try `sudo nano /etc/default/jenkins`

Comment: i have set port 8081.How to invoke jenkins??

Comment: Just restart the service as specified above and then go in your browser at `http://127.0.0.1:8081`. The Jenkins page should be there if there were no errors.

Comment: I was able to do with localhost:8081.Thanks

Comment: This solution gave me the hint I needed - In my case I was able to edit this file and change the following line: `HTTP_PORT=8080` which was referenced already in the `JENKINS_ARGS` line at the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 48):

For others still looking for answers you can go to `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` in CentOS/RHEL or `/etc/default/jenkins` in Debian based distributions and change the `JENKINS_PORT=` variable to whatever port you want. Restart jenkins, and it should be running on your desired port.

Comment: On Debian-based distros it's still `/etc/default/jenkins`. It's `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` for RHEL/CentOS.

Comment: On Debian-based distros the var is HTTP_PORT now

Answer (score 15):

The question is about ubuntu 12, but this not used anymore.
In modern debian/ubuntu systems take a look into:

/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service

change the port in the line

```
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=8080"
```

The port is still in /etc/default/jenkins but the change there is useless.
Tested in debian11.3

Comment: Thanks so much for saving me. Spent hours trying to understand why the config file is not being used.

Comment: And do not forget to reboot the VM

Comment: It has to do with systemd vs /etc/defaults.
There is more information on that:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services/659268

Answer (score 5):

in the recent version of jenkins if you install it with apt you have to change port like this:

```
sudo systemctl edit jenkins
```

and add lines below after line 2:

```
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=9090"
```

Comment: for my, the path is `/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service`

Answer (score 4):

1. First, run this command to open jenkins configurations:

   ```
    sudo nano /etc/default/jenkins
   ```
2. The only part you need to change is:

   ```
    #port for HTTP connector (default 8080; disable with -1)
    HTTP_PORT = 8080
   ```

   There you need to change to the desired port. For example:

   ```
    HTTP_PORT = 8081
   ```
3. Finally, Restart Jenkins service by running this command:

   ```
    sudo service jenkins restart
   ```

Then you're ready to open it with a new port.

Comment: @BassemRabia Have you restarted the jenkins service?

Answer (score 2):

In my case,I add

```
 HTTP_PORT="XXXX"
 JENKINS_ARGS="--httpPort=XXXX"
```

when defining the variables at the beginning of `/etc/default/jenkins`,it works .

Comment: You only need `HTTP_PORT`, the `JENKINS_ARGS` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

step 1 : sudo nano /etc/default/jenkins
open the nano file 
And change HTTP PORT:8080 to HTTP PORT : 8081

CTL+X and Click Y and ENTER

PORT will changing from 8080 to 8081
restart the jenkins

sudo service jenkins restart

Answer (score 0):

## Ubuntu 22.04 - Jenkins 2.346.2

#### To make Jenkins listen on port 80, follow these steps:

1. Change the `Environment="JENKINS_PORT=8080"` to `Environment="JENKINS_PORT=80"` in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service`

   ```bash
   sudo sed -i -e 's/Environment="JENKINS_PORT=[0-9]\+"/Environment="JENKINS_PORT=80"/' /usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service
   ```
2. Because the port 80 is a privileged port, you need to uncomment `AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service`

   ```bash
   sudo sed -i -e 's/^\s*#\s*AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE/AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE/' /usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service
   ```
3. Reload the systemctl daemon

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
4. Restart Jenkins

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl restart jenkins
   ```
5. Verify that Jenkins is listening on port 80

   ```bash
   sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep jenkins
   ```

Comment: You should use `systemctl edit jenkins` instead of editing `/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service` directly, otherwise your changes can be removed without warning

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins can be configured to run on a custom port.

```
sudo systemctl edit jenkins
```

Add the following:

```
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=9000"
```

Save and exit.

Restart Jenkins:

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```