# Can't get jenkins to run on different port on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I rented a VPS on [digitalocean](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/) that runs on Ubuntu 20.4. I installed jenkins following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-18-04. I exactly followed the instructions.

I want to run a Spring Boot App on this server and build a CI/CD pipeline with jenkins. I want the Spring Boot App to run on port 8080, so I need to move jenkins, which defaults to 8080. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28341352/10424056) which seemed to work for everyone in the thread:

> First open the /etc/default/jenkins file.
> Then under JENKINS_ARGS section, you can change the port like this HTTP_PORT=9999.
>
> Then you should restart Jenkins with sudo service jenkins restart.
>
> Then to check the status use this command sudo systemctl status jenkins

I exactly followed those few steps, but somehow Jenkins still runs on Port 8080. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: I tried exactly what you did right now with a local Jenkins on Ubuntu 21.04 and it worked. I'd ask DigitalOcean.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why but somehow it works now for me too. I don't know what I changed, but it works. This can be closed.

Answer (score 3):

Editing `/etc/default/jenkins` does not work anymore since version `2.332.1`, which relies on `systemd` rather than the `init` system ([documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/)).

Instead, run

```
systemctl edit jenkins
```

which will bring up an editor with an empty file. Paste the following contents:

```
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=8888"
```

Change the port as desired and save the file (in case of `nano` as editor with
`Ctrl + X`, `Y`).

Finally, restart Jenkins and it should pick up the new port:

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```